# Drush en failing

Tags: 8, drush

I was trying to install some modules via Drush 9 (9.2.3) on a Drupal 8 (8.5.3) site and I keep seeing the following.

```
[error]  Unable to install modules devel due to missing modules devel. 


[error]  Unable to install modules devel due to missing modules devel.
```

I was installing with the command:

```
drush en module_name
```

It is about as vanilla a site as you can get. I have barely started working on it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downloading contributed modules using Drush (9) [has become deprecated](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/pm/pm:download/). The recommended way to [download modules (and themes) is with Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#adding-modules). Assuming [Composer is installed](https://getcomposer.org/download/), you can add the contributed module to your project with `composer require drupal/<module_name>`.

Once the contributed module has been downloaded, you can enable it using `drush en <module_name>`.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to use Drush to download modules any more, when did this happen?

Comment: That happened in Drush 9. You can still use Drush 8 if you want to use  that, but it's also disabled there by default

Comment: So what if you do `composer require drupal/<module_name>`, it installs a tonne of stuff, then you do `drush en <module_name>` and it says *Unable to install modules <module_name> due to missing modules <module_name>*?

Comment: @user568458 Where did Composer install/place the Drupal <module_name> module exactly? If it's in the vendor directory, you have to indicate in the composer.json that packages of the type 'drupal-module' should be placed in your modules folder.